# how to load json file using the latest d3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization

I try to running a d3.js example, but failed in this function `d3.json();`

the error part is :

```
d3.json('force.json', function(error,graph) {
    console.log(graph);
    var link = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'links')
        .selectAll('link')
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('line');
});
```

I have put my json file in apache server but still get the error:

```
force.html:43   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'links' of undefined
```

and when I used console.log() to print it, I found the object, **graph** is `undefined`. so I feel there are some mistakes in loading json file.

---

this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>force</title>
</head>

<style>
    .links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
</style>

<body>
<svg></svg>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var svg_width = 960,
        svg_height = 600; 

    var circle_r = 5;

    var svg = d3.select('body').attr('width', svg_width).attr('height', svg_height);
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                       .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())     
                       .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d){  return d.id;  }))
                       .force("center", d3.forceCenter(svg_width/2, svg_height/2));

    d3.json('force.json', function(error,graph) {

      console.log(graph);

      var link = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'links')
                    .selectAll('link')
                    .data(graph.links)
                    .enter()
                    .append('line')
                    .attr('stroke-width',function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

      var node = svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'nodes')
                    .selectAll('circle')
                    .data(graph.nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append('circle')
                    .attr('r', circle_r)
                    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                    .call(d3.drag()
                            .on("start", dragstarted)
                            .on("drag", dragged)
                            .on("end", dragended));

        node.append('title').text(function(d){  return d.id; });

        simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on('tick', ticked);       //  set the simulation’s nodes.
        simulation.force('link').links(graph.links);            //  add or remove a force.

        function ticked(){
            link
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        }

    });     // d3.json end

        function dragstarted(d) {
          if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
          d.fx = d.x;
          d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(d) {
          d.fx = d3.event.x;
          d.fy = d3.event.y;
        }

        function dragended(d) {
          if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
          d.fx = null;
          d.fy = null;
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

this is my json file:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8},
    {"id": "BaronessT", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Enjolras", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Combeferre", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Feuilly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bahorel", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bossuet", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Joly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Grantaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9},
    {"id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Babet", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Claquesous", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Toussaint", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Child1", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Child2", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Brujon", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1}
  ]
}
```

Comment: where is the file located ?The html file and json file should be on the same folder and should called from a server not directly.

Comment: I'm sure I put both files in the same path. I used this command `python -m http.server 9999` in cmd to create http server.

Comment: can you upload your code ? both html and json file ?

Comment: sure，thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine. I think you are using an older version of d3.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script> // old version
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>    //use this
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but my d3.min.js is the latest file from github. thus i guess it is the newest d3.js.

Comment: for me it was working fine. I just copy pasted your code and added the latest d3 source. Are you sure that your server is running fine ?

Comment: um..I m sure, because my another code which used old d3 can work normally